# Forward input to external console application in R

Tags: r, console-application

I'm trying to run an external console application from R, which is working fine with the system command.

```
system("path-to-exe", invisible=FALSE, show.output.on.console=FALSE)
```

This command opens my exe in a new window.

However, the console application asks the user to input further commands like numbers to choose a menu item and I'm stuck with forwarding further commands to the external program. 
So my question, is it possible to input commands to the external console application and if yes, how?

Comment: You can use a pipe to write to the standard input of the command, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766391/how-to-get-output-from-a-pipe-connection-before-closing-it-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` to create your command.

```
  system (paste("path-to-exe ",arg1))
  system (paste("path-to-exe '",arg1,"'"))
```

Comment: hi. thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if I understand it. Does paste create one command with arguments or does it send multiple commands one after another, because that's what I want ?